# flutter-Bad response 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header

Tags: flutter, http, websocket

In many test pages you can request success, but in flutter throw the error “Bad response 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header”

```
void initWebSocket(){ 
    String path = "***"; 
    Future future = WebSocket.connect(path).then((wb){ 
        _webSocket = wb; 
        wb.listen((event) { 
            print("服务端---->:"+event); 
        },
        onError:(err){ 
            print("服务端----error--->:"+err); 
        },
        onDone: (){ 
            print("服务端----onDone"); 
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

Response:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n user-agent: Dart/2.12 (dart:io)\r\n connection: Upgrade\r\n cache-control: no-cache\r\n accept-encoding: gzip\r\n content-length: 0\r\n sec-websocket-version: 13\r\n host: **\r\n sec-websocket-extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n sec-websocket-key: rtbsyWoIQrZMpr1v9rN1Dw==\r\n upgrade: websocket\r\n \r\n [Full request URI: http://**/] [HTTP request 1/1] [Response in frame: 81]
```

Comment: Can you so your http call code including the parameters and headers you are sending?

Comment: code:void initWebSocket(){
    String path = "***";
    Future future = WebSocket.connect(path).then((wb){
      _webSocket = wb;
      wb.listen((event) {
        print("服务端---->:"+event);
      },onError:(err){
        print("服务端----error--->:"+err);
      },onDone: (){
      print("服务端----onDone");
      });
    });
  }

Comment: Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
    user-agent: Dart/2.12 (dart:io)\r\n
    connection: Upgrade\r\n
    cache-control: no-cache\r\n
    accept-encoding: gzip\r\n
    content-length: 0\r\n
    sec-websocket-version: 13\r\n
    host: **\r\n
    sec-websocket-extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n
    sec-websocket-key: rtbsyWoIQrZMpr1v9rN1Dw==\r\n
    upgrade: websocket\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://**/]
    [HTTP request 1/1]
    [Response in frame: 81]

Comment: Are you sending the path as `***` as shown in ` String path = "***"; ` or an actual web URL?

Comment: It's an actual url .Change other links in this code to access normally.

Comment: At the same time, the link I want to visit can also be linked normally in the webpage test